# Python Get all activity before an activity according to a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I hope you can help me, I want to get all the activity according to a condition.

I have a dataframe like this:

| ID | Number | Activity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Get Up |
| 1 | 2 | Wash |
| 1 | 3 | Dress Up |
| 2 | 1 | Get Up |
| 2 | 2 | Dress Up |
| 2 | 3 | Eat |
| 2 | 4 | Work |

I have as Target Activity **Dress Up**, so I should look for the Number of the activity and remove all the number after the number of target activity  The output:

| ID | Number | Activity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Get Up |
| 1 | 2 | Wash |
| 1 | 3 | Dress Up |
| 2 | 1 | Get Up |
| 2 | 2 | Dress Up |

I have tried to use the function where but **it removes all rows expect the one with target activity:**

```
df= pd.read_csv('data.csv')
End_act = 'Dress Up'
cond = df['Activity']==Endact
df = df[  df['Number']<= df['Number'].where(cond)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cummax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cummax.html) with compare values by `End_act` in column `Activity` with change order rows by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for set `True`s by all previous rows by `End_act`, last change order by original and filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
End_act = 'Dress Up'
m = (df.iloc[::-1]
       .assign(new = lambda x: x['Activity'].eq(End_act))
       .groupby('ID')['new']
       .cummax())

df = df[m.iloc[::-1]]
print (df)
   ID  Number  Activity
0   1       1    Get Up
1   1       2      Wash
2   1       3  Dress Up
3   2       1    Get Up
4   2       2  Dress Up
```

Your solution is changed with [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) for maximal index created by column `Number`:

```
End_act = 'Dress Up'
s = (df.set_index('Number')
        .assign(new = lambda x: x['Activity'].eq(End_act))
        .groupby('ID')['new']
        .transform('idxmax'))

df = df[df['Number'].le(s.to_numpy())]
print (df)
   ID  Number  Activity
0   1       1    Get Up
1   1       2      Wash
2   1       3  Dress Up
3   2       1    Get Up
4   2       2  Dress Up
```